# Forgot password dialog

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-networking

I have to add the forgot password in my application. I have to first send the email in the dialog box which will be used to check the corresponding password in the database and display the password in the notification.

```
public class OwnerLoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText txtlogin;
    EditText txtpassword;
    TextView lblforgotpassword;
    Button btnlogin;
    Button btnregister;
    MyDatabase database;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_owner_login);
        txtlogin=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtlogin);
        txtpassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtpassword);
        btnlogin=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnlogin);
        btnregister=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnregister);
        lblforgotpassword=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblforgotpassword);
        database=new MyDatabase(OwnerLoginActivity.this);

        lblforgotpassword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               Toast.makeText(OwnerLoginActivity.this, "forgot password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                forgotPassword();
            }
        });


        btnlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                checkLogin();
            }
        });

        btnregister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(OwnerLoginActivity.this, "Registered Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent obj=new Intent(OwnerLoginActivity.this,OwnerRegistrationActivity.class);
                startActivity(obj);
                finish();
            }
        });}


    public void checkLogin() {
        AndroidNetworking.post("http://192.168.43.38/internship_project/android_web_services/login.php")
            .addBodyParameter("email",txtlogin.getText().toString())
            .addBodyParameter("password",txtpassword.getText().toString()).setTag("Login").setPriority(Priority.MEDIUM)
            .build()
            .getAsJSONObject(new JSONObjectRequestListener() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    System.out.println(response.toString());
                    try {
                        if(response.getString("success").equals("1")){

                            Toast.makeText(OwnerLoginActivity.this, response.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent intent=new Intent(OwnerLoginActivity.this, ActDashboard.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                        else
                            Toast.makeText(OwnerLoginActivity.this, response.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(ANError anError) {
                    System.out.println(anError.toString());
                    Toast.makeText(OwnerLoginActivity.this, "Server time out please try again later", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            });
    }

    public void forgotPassword() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        LayoutInflater inflater=this.getLayoutInflater();
        final View dialogview=inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog,null);
        builder.setView(dialogview);
        final EditText edt=(EditText)dialogview.findViewById(R.id.email);
        builder.setTitle("Forgot password?");
        builder.setMessage("Enter your email id");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new     DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog b=builder.create();
        b.show();

    }
}
```

I have already added the alert box on onClick but the problem is I don't know how to get the password from the database. Do I have to add the Android Networking in the forgotPassword method?And to make a separate PHP file for it?

Edit: I did android networking in my program and called the notification method in it(I made two separate methods for the alert box and notification and different for Android networking). I called networking method in alert box method and called the password method in networking.It showed the alert box but the notification of the password is not working.It gives JSON object error

Comment: You want password from local database or server ??

Comment: I am using XAMPP

Comment: Very bad idea to store the passwords without any encryption and fetching the same. Instead of this allow the user to reset password.

Comment: that means you have local URL for get database value ?

Comment: Yes, I do have a local URL

Comment: Please don't store passwords in your database as clear text.

Comment: I am making the app for my college project. Its not a live one

Comment: ok than call api with the key of user email id.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the forgot.php file

Fetch the password from a database
and pass that password in JSON format